# Show that the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ is complete.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Please can you criticize my proof. Not sure if my assumptions are correct.

Show that the metric space $(\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, \| \cdot \|_\infty)$ is complete.

Let $(a_{p})_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

Then $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall p, q > N, \|a_{p} - a_{q}\|_\infty < 1 $

Choose $q = N+1$. Then $\|a_{p} - a_{N+1}\|_\infty < 1$

$\|a_p\|_\infty = \|a_p\ - a_{N+1} + a_{N+1}\|_\infty \leq \|a_p\ - a_{N+1}\|_\infty + \|a_{N+1}\|_\infty \leq 1 + \|a_{N+1}\|_\infty $

Take $M = max\{{\|a_1\|_\infty, ..., \|a_N\|_\infty, 1 + \|a_{N+1}\|_\infty}\}$. Then $0 \leq \|a_p\|_\infty \leq M$, so $\|a_p\|_\infty$ is bounded.

By the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem, there exists a convergent subsequence $(a_{p_k})_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$.

As $(a_{p})_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, $(a_{p})_{p \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also convergent.

Comment: Why $\mathbb R ^{n\times m}$ instead of $\mathbb R^k?$

Comment: The last sentence is unnecessary - you chose $(a_{p_k})$, in the line prior, to be the convergent subsequence guaranteed by the Bolzano-Wieirstrass Theorem. I might add (instead) a concluding sentence that says $(a_p)$ must converge to the same limit as $(a_{p_k})$.

Comment: @zhw Question is referring to nxm matrices but I understand that there is an isometry between R^k where k=nm and R^{nxm} with respect to the infinity norm for this question.

Comment: @user474330 Oops, amended last line!

Comment: How did $\|\,\|_\infty$ turn into $\|\,\|?$

Comment: @zhw Laziness in LaTeX... sorry. Thought it would be clear what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

If you want you can also use the equivalence of norms.

We know that  exist $M,N>0$ such that $$M||x||_2 \leq ||x||_{\infty}\leq N||x||_2$$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d$

where $||.||_2$ is the Euclideian norm.

In general using the fact that in a finite dimensional space,all norms are equivalent,you can prove completness of $\mathbb{R}^d$ with respect to a given norm $||.||_a$ by proving the completness with respect to a $\text{''simpler''}$ norm.